# Returning a value from a method multiple times

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I am trying to get this to record the coordinates of a mouse press, convert that into a grid reference and return that reference.  The problem is that I click it once and it returns a 1 in the array to show it has been populated.  When I click again it is not returning the reference.  I know it is calculating gridX and gridY as they appear on the console.

How can I get it to return the reference on every click?  Do I need to use some sort of while loop??

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class SwingPaintDemo3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    static void createAndShowGUI() {
        int[][][] lifeGrid = new int[62][42][2];
        int[] coords = new int[2];
        System.out.println("Created GUI on EDT? " +
                SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Paint Demo");
        f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280, 800));
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        JPanel subPanel = new JPanel();
        coords = MyPanel.changeValues(coords);
        int x = coords[0];
        int y = coords[1];
        lifeGrid[x][y][0] = 1;
        System.out.println(lifeGrid[x][y][0]);
        f.add(new MyPanel());
        JButton seed = new JButton("SEED");
        subPanel.add(seed);
        seed.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 50));
        seed.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                System.out.println("Seed");
            }
        });
        JButton start = new JButton("START");
        subPanel.add(start);
        start.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 50));
        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae1) {
                System.out.println("Start");


            }
        });
        start.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 50));
        JButton stop = new JButton("STOP");
        subPanel.add(stop);
        stop.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 50));
        JButton reset = new JButton("RESET");
        subPanel.add(reset);
        reset.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 50));
        f.add(subPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

MyPanel class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    static int gridX = 0;
    static int gridY = 0;
    int squareX = 1280;
    int squareY = 800;

    public MyPanel() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                squareX = e.getX();
                squareY = e.getY();
                if ((squareX > 20 & squareX < 920) & (squareY > 50 & squareY < 650)) {
                    gridX = (squareX - 20) / 15 + 1;
                    gridY = (squareY - 50) / 15 + 1;
                    squareX = (squareX - 20) / 15 * 15 + 20;
                    squareY = (squareY - 50) / 15 * 15 + 50;
                    System.out.println(gridX + " " + gridY);
                    repaint(squareX, squareY, 15, 15);
                } else {

                }
            }
        });

    }

    static int[] changeValues(int[] grid) {
        grid[0] = gridX;
        grid[1] = gridY;
        return grid;
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(squareX, squareY, 13, 13);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(squareX, squareY, 13, 13);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. If your goal is just monitoring mouse click event you have already done it and you can call any methods you want for any proposes.

Comment: Your question is really not clear to me. You wrote: _the coordinates of a mouse press_. Are you referring to method `getX()` and `getY()` of class `java.awt.event.MouseEvent`? You also wrote: _convert that into a grid reference_. Are you converting the mouse coordinates to a grid reference? What part of your code is doing that? You also wrote: _I click it once and it returns a 1 in the array_ What "array" are you referring to? You also wrote: _I know it is calculating gridX and gridY as they appear on the console._ Do you mean the console of your IDE?

Comment: Change your mouseClicked to mousePressed.